# .zshenv file broken? After adding to it in order to install linageos on a phone. Beginner

Tags: terminal, macos

I was trying to install lineageos on a phone on mac and added this to the zshenv file in the user folder:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/adb-fastboot/platform-tools" ] ; then
 export PATH="$HOME/adb-fastboot/platform-tools:$PATH"
fi
```

It now lookes like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2513
\cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Bold;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red25\green28\blue31;\red242\green242\blue242;\red0\green0\blue109;
\red210\green0\blue53;\red14\green110\blue109;\red14\green114\blue164;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c12941\c14510\c16078;\cssrgb\c96078\c96078\c96078;\cssrgb\c0\c0\c50196;
\cssrgb\c86667\c6667\c26667;\cssrgb\c0\c50196\c50196;\cssrgb\c0\c52549\c70196;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0

\f0\b\fs28 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 if
\f1\b0  
\f0\b [
\f1\b0  \cf4 \strokec4 -d\cf2 \strokec2  \cf5 \strokec5 "\cf6 \strokec6 $HOME\cf5 \strokec5 /adb-fastboot/platform-tools"\cf2 \strokec2  
\f0\b ]
\f1\b0  ; 
\f0\b then\

\f1\b0 \cf7 \strokec7 export \cf6 \strokec6 PATH
\f0\b \cf2 \strokec2 =
\f1\b0 \cf5 \strokec5 "\cf6 \strokec6 $HOME\cf5 \strokec5 /adb-fastboot/platform-tools:\cf6 \strokec6 $PATH\cf5 \strokec5 "\cf2 \strokec2 \

\f0\b fi
\f1\b0 \

if [ -d "$HOME/adb-fastboot/platform-tools" ] ; then
 export PATH="$HOME/adb-fastboot/platform-tools:$PATH"
fi
}
```

When I open the terminal i now get this message:

```
/Users/kalyan/.zshenv:1: command not found: \ufeff{rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf2513
/Users/kalyan/.zshenv:2: parse error near `}'
```

Do you know what might be wrong?

Thank you :)!
Have a nice day

Comment: Did you edit the file with Microsoft Word or a similar document processor? You should use a pure text editor.

Comment: hello, first with the text editor and then with sublime text

Comment: Your file seems to be in RTF format. Remove all the RTF stuff and leave only the pure text that should be in the file. You wrote that you *added* the lines to the `zshenv` file. In the RTF text in your question I don't see anything else that might belong into this file, so you might have replaced the old contents instead of adding to it.

Comment: Thank you! I think I see what you mean. Just don't know what the rtf formatting is in detail. I now asked the apple support community for a sample file. :) Thanks again